# PHP - Most efficient way to filter two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, filtering

I have a question on what is the most performant way to filter two arrays of objects. I have two arrays of products from different systems and i want to work out which products have been removed from one array and then return the products that have been removed.

See the current function i have below which i know is super slow.

```
 public function checkRemove($externalProducts, $localProducts){
    //Push all the SKU codes from feed to an array();
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($externalProducts->products as $product) {
        if($product->StockNumber != null){
            array_push($arr, $product->StockNumber);
        }
    }
    //Loop through the local products 
    $productsRemove = [];
    foreach ($localProducts->products as $key => $localProduct) {
        if(in_array($localProduct->sku, $arr)){

        }else{
            array_push($productsRemove, $localProduct);
        }
    }    
    return $productsRemove;
}

$externalProducts = {
"Filter": {
    "Title": "All Products"
},
"Products": [{
        "Type": "Jacket",
        "Price": 75,
        "ExpiryDate": "2018-06-30",
        "StockNumber": "180220/003",
        "Created": "2018-02-20 12:24:06",
        "Modified": "2018-05-30 02:00:23"
    },
    {
        "Type": "Jeans",
        "Price": 150,
        "ExpiryDate": "2018-06-30",
        "StockNumber": "180221/004",
        "Created": "2017-08-10 15:11:44",
        "Modified": "2018-05-30 02:00:22"
    },
    {
        "Type": "Jacket",
        "Price": 240,
        "ExpiryDate": "2018-06-30",
        "StockNumber": "150804/012",
        "Created": "2015-08-04 17:03:42",
        "Modified": "2018-05-30 02:00:22"
    }
    ]
}
$internalProducts = "localProducts": [{
    "title": "Fur Coat",
    "id": 16526,
    "created_at": "2018-05-17T10:15:45Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-17T10:15:45Z",
    "sku": "180514/001",
    "price": "75.00",
    "regular_price": "75.00",
    "categories": [
        "Jackets",
    ],
},
{
    "title": "Ripped Jeans",
    "id": 16527,
    "created_at": "2018-05-17T10:15:45Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-17T10:15:45Z",
    "sku": "180221/004",
    "price": "150.00",
    "regular_price": "150.00",
    "categories": [
        "Jeans",
    ],
},
{
    "title": "Leather Jacket",
    "id": 16528,
    "created_at": "2018-05-17T10:15:45Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-17T10:15:45Z",
    "sku": "150804/012",
    "price": "240.00",
    "regular_price": "240.00",
    "categories": [
        "Jackets",
    ],
    }
]
```

Comment: Why is it `super slow`? You made tests?

Comment: Can you give us two sample arrays? How the arrays are structured is important to the answer. I mean the $externalProducts and $localProducts

Comment: @Andreas i have updated the code in the question

Comment: @u_mulder yeah its super slow as there is a huge amount of products in each array.

Comment: @SimonBL Your internalproducts is invalid json.

Comment: @Andreas it was just a sample i quickly wrote to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

You can provide a callback function which will be run for each element in the array. If the callback function returns true, the current value from the array is returned in the result array.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to iterate over one array at least. It is `$localProducts`. So, for `$localProducts` there're no improvements. But you can improve `$externalProducts` - add a special method (if you can) that will return `StockNumbers` only. More effective will be if `StockNumbers` will be of structure as:

```
[
    'stocknumber1' => true,
    'stocknumber2' => true,
    'stocknumber3' => true,
    'stocknumber4' => true,
    'stocknumber5' => true,
]
```

This will improve your search, as checking `isset($StockNumbers['stocknumber4'])` is **faster** than `in_array` or `array_search`.

If you can't change structure of `$externalProducts->products`, than build array of stock numbers in a loop:

```
public function checkRemove($externalProducts, $localProducts){
    //Push all the SKU codes from feed to an array();
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($externalProducts->products as $product) {
        if ($product->StockNumber != null){
            // Again I add sku as key, not as value
            $arr[$product->StockNumber] = true;
        }
    }

    //Loop through the local products 
    $productsRemove = [];
    foreach ($localProducts->products as $localProduct) {
        // check with `isset` is faster
        if (isset($arr[$localProduct->sku])) {
            array_push($productsRemove, $localProduct);
        }
    }    
    return $productsRemove;
}
```